# How to use XDP_REDIRECT in egress path?

Tags: linux, xdp-bpf

How to use xdp_redirect in egress path?
I know how use it by TC_ACT_REDIRECT but dont know by XDP_REDIRECT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux does not support setting XDP programs on the egress path as of this writing. There are [proposals](https://lore.kernel.org/netdev/20200513014607.40418-7-dsahern@kernel.org/T/) to add it, but it has not been accepted yet.